# call for an array change in a function of struct is not working

Tags: c++, function, struct

I am trying to call the **Debug function** of **struct Matrix**.
But it's **not printing anything**.

When I call the constructor of the struct Matrix it prints the values of array a(all zeroes). But after calling the Debug function to print the same matrix doesn't print anything. It just runs and stops.

**Declaring Debug2** is giving **errors** as follows
**1. variable or field Debug2 declared void​**
**2. missing template arguments before &**
**3. m was not declared in this scope do you mean 'tm'?**

Any Help? Please.

***EDIT**
Problem solved. Description in code. Thanks to Everyone.
Code below.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename A>
struct Matrix {
    vector<vector<A>> a;
    int r = 0, c = 0;

    // not working
    Matrix (A x, A y, A v = 0) { 
        vector<vector<A>> a = vector<vector<A>>(x, vector<A> (y, v));
        r = x, c = y }; 
    
    // this is working
    Matrix (A x, A y, A v = 0): a(vector<vector<A>>(x, vector<A> (y, v))), r(x), 
    c(y) {}  

    Matrix operator + (Matrix& other) {
        Matrix<A> ans(r, c);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].size(); j++) {
                ans.a[i][j] = a[i][j] + other.a[i][j];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    };
    void Debug() {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
    };
};

// not working
void Debug2(Matrix& m) {
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <m.r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.c; j++) {
            cout << m.a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
};

//working
template<typename A> void Debug2(Matrix<A>& m) {
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <m.r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.c; j++) {
            cout << m.a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
};


int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    Matrix<int> k(5, 7);
    k.Debug();
    Debug2(k);
   // cout << k.r << k.c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Matrix` is a class template. there is no template arg in `void Debug2(Matrix& m) {`. You can't use a class template as function parameter.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` `using namespace std;` `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);` what's up alwith this? Why are you using it?

Comment: bits/stdc++.h contains all the functions of library. And cin and cout are slow so the unsyncing and tie to null. I actually read it on website and just copied it for competitive programming. More info here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-for-competitive-programming/

Comment: @ThomasSablik any suggestions why Debug inside struct not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a local variable `a` in your constructor shadowing the member variable `a`. Use a member initializer list:

```
Matrix (A x, A y, A v = 0): a = vector<vector<A>>(x, vector<A> (y, v)), r = x, c = y {
    // cout << "\n";
    // for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    //  for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
    //      cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
    //  }
    //  cout << '\n';
    // }
};
```

You need a template argument for `Matrix` in `Debug2`:

```
template<typename A>
void Debug2(Matrix<A>& m) {
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <m.r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.c; j++) {
            cout << m.a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`r = x, c = y;` should be `r = x; c = y;` as operator "," has very different meaning than ";".

"Matrix &m" doesn't make sense as "Matrix" is a class template so it needs a template argument, e.g. `template<class T> void Debug2(Marix<T>& m)`

Comment: It did compiled without error. But still not printing the vector.